# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Server on a PowerBook G4 - Can't get partitions to work

Tags: 14.04, server, system-installation, powerpc

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 on an old PowerBook G4 I had lying about.  I get through the installer to the point where it tries to create the partitions.  The first attempt I just told it to "Use Entire Disk", so the installer would just make it's own partitions, but this complained about the NewWorld partition was missing.  So, then after MUCH struggle with getting rid of the LVM partitions the first "Use Entire Disk" option created, I made a partition for NewWorld as the first partition, then remade the same partitions the installer did, but this time it complained that the partitions were overlapping.

Next I booted to a PPC Gentoo disk I had made.  Used it to recreate the partitions using `mac-fdisk`, such that the Apple and bootstrap partitions were back in partitions 1 and 2.  Then booted back to Ubuntu installer.  This time I did a manual partition, created a NewWorld partition followed by a /boot, sway, and /.  Marked both the /boot and the / to format, but when I try to go to the next steps I get the following errors:

1. The file system on /dev/sda3 assigned to / has not been marked for fomatting (it has been, I triple-quadruple checked it!)
2. If I then pick `No`, I get: The installer needs to remove operating system files from the target, but was unable to do so.  The installer cannot continue.

The only option is to "Continue", which sends my back to the partition gui.  Again, I have verified that the / partition is indeed marked for formatting.  It is set as an Ext4 partition, if that matters.  I am in the process of doing an erase right now, but it's barely ticking up the percentage so it looks like it might take some time to complete.

The partitions I show in my list are as follows:

1. Apple - 32.3kb
2. bootstrap - 819.2kb
3. nwboot - 10mb
4. /boot (ext2) - 1gb
5. swap - 10gb
6. / (ext4) - 309.1gb

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I found closely related to your question - https://www.jeremymorgan.com/tutorials/linux/how-to-install-linux-ppc-powerbook-g4/

hopefully it helps, it is a tutorial on how to install on a powerbook g4.

Comment: Unfortunately these are very similar steps I took to perform the install myself, except in my case I don't have the pretty graphical installer.  The problem isn't a lack of understanding HOW to perform the install.  Ubuntu typically makes that pretty simple to figure out.  The problem is when it tries to partition the drive it fails in many ways that make no sense.  Why would "Use Entire Disk" not create a required partition?  Why is it complaining that my partitions are overlapping?  Why is it saying I had not selected to format /? Why is it saying it can't remove files that are not there?